# Ruby on Rails asset pipeline appears to be adding styles that don't exist

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm completely stumped by this. My SCSS file shows this:

```
.segmented-control {
  li .field_with_errors label {
      border-color: #db5757;
  }
}
```

But when I load the page and inspect the css, it shows this:

```
/* line 1382, /general.scss */
.segmented-control li .field_with_errors label,
.form-item-segmented-control li .field_with_errors label {
  border-color: #db5757;
}
```

The line number, 1382, points exactly to the first code snippet that I showed. Yet in the compiled version it includes an extra selector that includes `.form-item-segmented-control`.

I do use `.form-item-segmented-control` in other places in the CSS, but not here. And it is definitely *not* nested or anything like that.

I'm utterly stumped. Any ideas of what Rails could possibly be doing? Or even ideas of how I could debug further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some more debugging I believe I figured it out. It looks like it was due to an `@extend` that I had used earlier in the file. I hadn't realized all of the effects of `@extend` previously.

It looks like if I do something like:

```
.form-item-segmented-control {
    @extend .segmented-control;
}
```

*ever* in the file, it will then add the `.form-item-segmented-control` selector to *all* occurrences of `.segmented-control`. An important nuance to note, though, is that it will NOT do the same for occurrences of `.segmented-control` in other SCSS partials; the `@extend` only affects the file it is used in.